# How To Debug Internet Explorer Requests?

Tags: networking, dns, apache-http-server, internet-explorer, bind

I am having a problem with my website, insurgent.info, which Internet Explorer will not display (as in, no error page or even any attempt at loading the site - the browser immediately passes the web address to the default search engine), but the site displays fine and with no problems in Waterfox.

I have checked the site using zonemaster.net and know that there are no DNS issues; so I am trying to find a way to capture the error in the Apache logs, or to see how BIND is handling the requests, because even mod_log_forensic fails to give me any information whatsoever.

It is literally as though IE is not even able to find the site, never mind connect (and, yes, I am aware that my DNS propagation is currently only around 98%); but Waterfox has been connecting without issue throughout several modifications over the past couple of weeks even though IE has never once been able to connect to the site.

I have tried to keep this brief and to the point, but please tell me if more information is required.

Comment: If `insurgent.info` is your domain, note that it fails with Google's `8.8.8.8` public DNS server (but works on `8.8.4.4`). So it does appear to be a DNS propagation issue.

Comment: Hm, doesn't work on `8.8.4.4` now. I do notice that `www.insurgent.info` works - Firefox/Waterfox may be trying the `www.` subdomain automatically, and that no `A`/`AAAA` record exists on `insurgent.info`.

Comment: Confirmed against the authoritative nameservers with a `dig ANY insurgent.info @ns1.insurgent.info` vs a `dig ANY www.insurgent.info @ns1.insurgent.info`. You only have `A`/`AAAA` defined on the `www.` subdomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddler is a generic debugging proxy that will capture HTTP and HTTPS requests.

However, if you suspect you are having DNS issues, you will instead need to use Wireshark and carefully filter the captured data.

Alternatively, you can test with the `ping` command, which will use the same DNS system and cache that IE uses. The `nslookup` command does not use the DNS cache and will instead make the request directly to the default or specified DNS server, and can additionally test against a specified server.

---

To prevent the redirection to search engine on failure, you can force IE to treat as a domain and show the error page by specifying the protocol, i.e. instead of navigating to `example.com`, type `http://example.com` (or `https://example.com`) in the URL bar.

Comment: Yes, using the http : // www . protocol _does_ enable access to the site via Internet Explorer (thanks), so I have re-added the A and AAAA records (previously I had removed them, leaving only the two records for the www IN A and www IN AAAA), and will now wait and see what happens. I will check out Fiddler, too, - it looks as though it should be quite useful (Wireshark is a pain in the proverbial because it does not appear to have a pure command line version).

Comment: Also, in case you are wondering, I originally removed the additional A and AAAA records because they appeared to be causing a DNS conflict (which, yes, disappeared after their removal).

Comment: I eventually solved this problem completely by resetting Internet Explorer and refusing to install Microsoft's "recommended settings" package; so the website is definitely accessible via IE with no rewrites, special rules, exceptions, or any other such requirements, and without needing www or http:// pre-pending to the address.